# $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(s, 0)=sX_p$, $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(0, v)=v$

Tags: differential-geometry

In my differential geometry textbook there is a claim: with the standard identification $T_o\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$, then tangent map to $\Phi$ (a flow of vector field X) at (0, p) is $T_{(0, p)}:\mathbb{R}\times T_pM\to T_pM$.

And then it said $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(0, v)=v$, since $\Phi|_{0\times M}$ is the identity map of M, and $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(s, 0)=sX_p$ since $\Phi|_{\mathbb{R}\times \{p\}}: \mathbb{R}\to M$ is the integral curve of X through p.

I don't understand why $\Phi|_{0\times M}$ is the identity map of M makes $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(0, v)=v$ true, and why $\Phi|_{\mathbb{R}\times \{p\}}: \mathbb{R}\to M$ is the integral curve of X through p makes $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(s, 0)=sX_p$ true.
(Though, I understand why $\Phi|_{0\times M}$ is the identity map and why $\Phi|_{\mathbb{R}\times \{p\}}: \mathbb{R}\to M$ is the integral curve of X through p)

I think for $f\in C^\infty (M)$, by definition of tangent map, $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(0, v)(f)=(0, v)(f\circ\Phi)$, $(T_{(0, p)}\Phi)(s, 0)(f)=(s, 0)(f\circ\Phi)$, but I don't where to go.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that you have some typos concerning the point we are finding the differential of and whether we are finding the differential of the whole map or some restriction. Please double check to make sure everything is written correctly. :)

Comment: @moboDawn_φ edited :)